# Trimmed SD discrepancy in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create an R script that calculates a 5% and 10% trimmed mean and SD. I uploaded the data on [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TVyhvNM-Uvq36GMdTpBIoatE2WONZSJx/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117246601612351628839&rtpof=true&sd=true) in order to enable replication.

My attempt using already existent commands:

```
library(xlsx)
library(chemometrics)

df <- read.xlsx("output.xlsx","Sheet1")
varb <- 'age'
test <- df[[varb]]
trimm <- 0.1
location <- mean(test,trim=trimm)
disp <- chemometrics::sd_trim(test,trim=trimm)
print(location)
print(disp)
```

Result:

```
> print(location)
[1] 70.52361
> print(disp)
[1] 9.266804
```

My attempt using custom code (inspired by @maarvd in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67838360/find-10-highest-and-lowest-values-trim-all-columns-in-r))

```
df <- read.xlsx("output.xlsx","Sheet1")
varb <- 'age'
test <- df[[varb]]
test <- test[test >= quantile(test, 0.1) & test <= quantile(test, 0.9)]
location <- mean(test)
disp <- sd(test)
```

Result:

```
> print(location)
[1] 70.52361
> print(disp)
[1] 6.223547
```

Both seem fine to me, but the SD comes out different! Much as I experimented, I can't figure out why! Which one is correct?

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error 
messages, code or packages, etc.) are generally off topic 
here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: `trimm <- 0.1` trims 1/10th of the data, but your second code block trims 1/5th of the data (top 0.1 and bottom 0.1). Also, reading the documentation says "the appropriate consistency correction" is applied by default, whatever that means. Which one is correct depends on how much of the data you want to trim.